# Nginx - how to upstream frontends to a path e.g. 127.0.0.1/test/ usig location but 404 error

Tags: nginx

Ho,

Below is my config for nginx.  If I use "location /" and I browse to 127.0.0.1 I see the web page.  If I use "location /ph/" I get 404: Not Found.  How can I used a path?  The app that   that is listing on 8051 is a python cyclone app.

http {

```
upstream frontends {
    server 127.0.0.1:8051;
}

##
# Basic Settings
##

sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 30;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
# server_tokens off;
# server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
# server_name_in_redirect off;

include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

    # Only retry if there was a communication error, not a timeout
    # on the Tornado server (to avoid propagating "queries of death"
    # to all frontends)
    proxy_next_upstream error;

server {
    listen   80;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;

            location /ph/ {
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://frontends;
        }
```

Comment: hi did you ever resolve this?

Comment: did you tried using location /ph  ?

Comment: I got hit in my server but its not returning the response back to client, where might be error?!